# What is the difference beween $uri and $uri/ in the try_files directive?

Tags: nginx

This is the configuration:

```
index index.html;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
}
```

I make a request at http://localhost/path/a/. I assume this is the URI, so at the $uri stage try_files will look at /path/a/ and serve index.html if there's any.

I read from the docs that `It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”.` but this does not make any sense for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is exactly the `$uri/` part that makes nginx assuming an URI can be a directory name and looking for an index file presence inside it.

Assume the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html
         ├── a
         │   └── index.html
         ├── b
         │   ├── index.html
         │   └── index.htm
         ├── c
         │   └── test.html
         ...
```

and the following nginx config:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.htm index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Here is what happened with the following `curl` requests:

- ```
  curl http://localhost/a
  ```

  Returns a redirect:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://localhost/a/
  ```
- ```
  curl http://localhost/a/
  ```

  Returns the `/var/www/html/a/index.html` file contents.
- ```
  curl http://localhost/b
  ```

  Returns a redirect:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://localhost/b/
  ```
- ```
  curl http://localhost/b/
  ```

  Returns the `/var/www/html/b/index.htm` file contents (index files existence is checked in order they are specified using the `index` directive).
- ```
  curl http://localhost/c
  ```

  Returns a redirect:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://localhost/c/
  ```
- ```
  curl http://localhost/c/
  ```

  Since there is no index file in the `/var/www/html/c/` directory, `curl` command will return an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` unless you have an `autoindex on;` directive in your config (in that case nginx will return the `/var/www/html/c/` directory listing).

If your nginx config will look like

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.htm index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

each of the above requests now will return an `HTTP 404 Not Found` error. An `autoindex` directive, if being present, will have no effect. The only way to get an `index.html` contents will be to specify it explicitly, e.g. `http://localhost/a/index.html`, `http://localhost/b/index.htm` etc.

The very important yet absolutely non-obvious thing is that an `index` directive being used with `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` can cause an internal redirect. For example, if you will have the following configuration:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.htm index.html;
    location / {
        add_header X-Test test1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /a/index.html {
        add_header X-Test test2;
    }
}
```

request `http://localhost/a/` will cause an internal redirect from `/a/` to `/a/index.html` and return the `/var/www/html/a/index.html` file contents with the custom `X-Test` header set to `test2`, not to `test1`!

The last thing worth to mention is that `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` is the default nginx behavior, so

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

and

```
location / {}
```

locations are totally equal.

**Update**

An additional question from OP:

> My thoughts were: `$uri` examines URI as it is and `$uri/` examines URI as a directory looking out for an index file. For `http://localhost/a` with `try_files $uri /file.html =404;` I get `file.html`. Good for now! For `http://localhost/a` with `try_files $uri/ /file.html =404;` I get `file.html` too. Why? I was expecting the `index.html`. Furthermore, `try_files $uri $uri/ /file.html =404;` will get me the `index.html`.

A really good question! Without answering it the whole answer will be somehow incomplete. Let's look what happens here.

Having the `http://localhost/a/` request and `try_files $uri/ /file.html =404;` directive in your nginx config, on a first step nginx checked the `/var/www/html/a/` directory for being a directory, next checked it for an index file presence, found an `index.html` file inside it and made an internal redirect from `/a/` to `/a/index.html`. On a second step, being inside the same location block, nginx checks the `/var/www/html/a/index.html` for being a directory, but it isn't! And since you don't have an `$uri` component as a `try_files` directive parameter, it goes for the next check for the `/var/www/html/file.html` file, found it and returns its content.

You may think that using the `try_files` directive without an `$uri` parameter is completely useless therefore. Usually it is, but it can be a use case to do it, for example when you want to hide your internal site structure. Here is an example:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ /index\.html$ {
        internal; # only accessible via internal URI rewrite
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    location ~ \.(js|css|jpe?g|png)$ {
        # serve the assets in a usual way
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Making that `location ~ /index\.html$ { ... }` an internal, you prevent direct access to your `index.html` files via requests like `http://localhost/a/index.html` (an `HTTP 404 Not Found` will be returned instead). However requests like `http://localhost/a/` remains workable because of the internal URI rewrite by `index` directive together with `try_files $uri/ =404` one.

Comment: Great explanation! My thoughts were: $uri examines URI as it is and $uri/ examines URI as a directory looking out for an index file. For http://localhost/a `try_files $uri /file.html = 404; ` I get file.html. Good for now! For http://localhost/a `try_files $uri/ /file.html = 404; ` I get file.html too. Why? I was expecting the index.html. Furthermore, `try_files $uri $uri/ /file.html = 404;` will get me the index.html.

Comment: Good question! See the update to the answer.

Comment: This answer needs many more upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. Minor point: you mention, in the case for ```curl http://localhost/c/```, that it returns a 403 code; why not a 404?